# Slice the column list (years) based on first character

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, data-science

I have extracted the list of columns from my df, which are of string type and look like this: 1999-1 (as in the first month of 1999).

I want to drop all columns before 2000 so I extracted the column list and used list comprehension to check if the first character of the string is 1.

The code runs but my "columns_to_drop" list is empty.

```
def convert_housing_data_to_quarters():
    data_source = pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv') #this is the df 
    data_source['State'] = data_source['State'].map(states) 
    data_source.drop(['Metro','CountyName','RegionID','SizeRank'],axis=1,inplace=1)
    data_source.set_index(['State','RegionName'],inplace=True)
    columns = list(data_source.columns)
    columns_to_drop = [col for col in columns if col[0]=="1"]
    data_source.drop(columns_to_drop,axis=1,inplace=1)
    return data_source

convert_housing_data_to_quarters()
```

Comment: without data, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: What is value of `columns` just before you compute `columns_to_drop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1999-1','2000-1','2000-10'])

df = df.loc[:, pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y-%m').year >= 2000]
print (df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2000-1, 2000-10]
Index: []
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.str[0] != '1']

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2000-1, 2000-10]
Index: []
```

All together:

```
def convert_housing_data_to_quarters():
    #set index from columns in read csv
    data_source = pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv', index_col=['State','RegionName'])
    data_source.drop(['Metro','CountyName','RegionID','SizeRank'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data_source = data_source.loc[:, data_source.columns.str[0] != '1']
    return data_source

df = convert_housing_data_to_quarters()
print (df.columns)
Index(['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06',
       '2000-07', '2000-08', '2000-09', '2000-10',
       ...
       '2017-02', '2017-03', '2017-04', '2017-05', '2017-06', '2017-07',
       '2017-08', '2017-09', '2017-10', '2017-11'],
      dtype='object', length=215)
```